# Destination folder is empty, imagemin webp is not working

Tags: node.js, image-compression, webp, sharp

```
imagemin([__dirname + 'images/raw/*.{jpg,png}'], {
    destination: __dirname + '/images/converted/',
    plugins: [
      imageminWebp({
        quality: 75,
        resize: {
          width: 1000,
          height: 0
        }
      })
    ]
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Images optimized');
  })
```

The code is working fine and I get the message "Images optimized" but the destination folder is empty. Nothing is happening with the code. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your input path. `__dirname` strips the trailing slash, so assuming your working directory is `/Users/user/my-project`, you end up with a glob like this:

`/Users/user/my-projectimages/raw/*.{jpg,png}`.

It is generally advised to join paths via `path.join()` for consistency:

```
const path = require('path');
const inputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'images/raw/*.{jpg,png}');
// /Users/user/my-project/images/raw/*.{jpg,png}
```